# What is the difference between html.AttributeEncode vs html.Encode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between html.AttributeEncode vs html.Encode?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[AttributeEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.attributeencode.aspx) converts only a handful of characters:

- "
- &
- <
- \

[Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.encode.aspx) does a full HtmlEncode, encoding **any** characters that aren't in Html.

Comment: @daghan According to the documentation, it does not, thus you should **not** use AttributeEncode if placing inside single quoted attribute like `title='single quoted'`: "The result should be used only for attributes that are in double quotation marks. Security issues might arise if you use the AntiForgeryToken method to encode attributes that are in single quotation marks." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492240.aspx