# JSON convert JsonResult to javascript string without encoding quotations

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to convert a `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller.JsonResult` to a string using `ASP.NET Core`

Here is my code in ASP.NET MVC

```
public async Task<string> GetJsonData()
{
    //...
    var result = GetMyComplexObject();

    //using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert method
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Json(result));
    return jsonString;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var myViewModel= new MyViewModel();
    myViewModel.JsonString = GetJsonData();
    return View(myViewModel);
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    //...
    public string JsonString { get; set; }
}
```

and in my cshtml

```
var dataSet = {@(Model.JsonString))};
```

However in the generated source instead of the fields being in quotations, they are html encoded  e.g. `&quot;field1&quot;`

Instead of running string replaces is there not a neater way to convert a `JsonResult` to `string`

Comment: in debugger it shows that way

Comment: you might try JIL (disclaimer this was a tool made by SO) https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In ASP.Net 5 there is a [`JsonHelper`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/d8d2e54506c7b1973156316f1dd82c6226de2c95/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/JsonHelper.cs) directly available in the razor views via `@Json.Serialize`, so you can write something like this in your razor view:

```
var foo = @Json.Serialize(model);
```

This is very similar to manually doing:

```
var foo = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model))
```

The problem in both cases is that JSON.Net by default serializes but does not XSS-sanitizes the output. This means the contents of **model** are not escaped, leaving your code open for [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Prevention_Rules) if model depends on user input. For example:

```
@{
    var model = new
    {
        prop1 = 1,
        prop2 = "</script><script>alert('o hai');</script>",
        prop3 = false
    };
}
var foo = @Json.Serialize(model);
```

You could use the `Json.Serialize` overload that lets you specify `JsonSerializerSettings`, so you can set [`StringEscapeHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm) as EscapeHtml:

> HTML (<, >, &, ', ") and control characters (e.g. newline) are escaped.

```
var foo = @Json.Serialize(model, new JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml });
```

PS. I have raised an issue on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5949) to include default html escaping in the JsonHelper.

**Approaches used in previous versions**

If you search about this same question on stack overflow, you will see there used to be a `Json.Encode` helper in earlier versions of MVC, so you could serialize [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072787/1836935), manually performing the json serialization. This seems replaced by `Json.Serialize` which is not safe by default.

There also used to be a helper `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` that could be used to manually encode json literals. This seems to be there in ASP.Net 5 as `IJavaScriptStringEncoder`. The only problem is that when combined with Newtonsoft.Json (The default json formatter in ASP.Net 5), it will encode too much for a valid json literal (like the double quotes in property names). However it will produce a valid string that can be parsed on the browser with JSON.parse (So probably [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727191/1836935) should work too):

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.IJavaScriptStringEncoder encoder;
...
var foo = JSON.parse("@encoder.JavaScriptStringEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model))");
```

Be also aware that by looking at the newest source code, the `IJavaScriptStringEncoder` will be replaced by `System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder` in RC2.

Comment: This is what i was looking for `@Json.Serialize(Model);`, great answer as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! Using the ASP.Net 5 version with JsonSerializerSettings may require the developer to add `@using Newtonsoft.Json` to the view in order to bring JsonSerializerSettings's containing namespace into scope.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Newtonsoft

```
"Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8",
```

and then on your JsonResult Object in your Controller

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

and

```
var jsonResult = Json(myObject);

string jsonString= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

**String - JavaScriptSerializer: (Can't use in ASP.NET Core)**

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonResult.Data);
```

**Object - Newtonsoft.Json:**

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult.Data, Formatting.Indented, new KeysJsonConverter(typeof(OBJECT)));
```

**KeysJsonConverter**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestApp.Helpers
{
    // Creates a custom JsonConverter that overrides serialization to add a keys property.

    public class KeysJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        private readonly Type[] _types;

        public KeysJsonConverter(params Type[] types)
        {
            _types = types;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

            if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
            {
                t.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                JObject o = (JObject)t;
                IList<string> propertyNames = o.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

                o.AddFirst(new JProperty("Keys", new JArray(propertyNames)));

                o.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
        }
    }
}
```

**.cshtml**

```
 var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Not sure where i got **KeysJsonConverter** from but i have used it in a few projects i have built and it works very well, credit to whoever wrote it originally.

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer from what I know cannot be used in ASP.NET Core as it is part of the System namespace

Comment: He is serializing a object anyway using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert method, which i have shown above :) you are right you can't use JavaScriptSerializer in ASP.NET Core. But you can use Newtonsoft.Json as its a dependency of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.